# C# Regex pattern for finding a tag in a string

Tags: c#, regex

For the below string,I want to select only the inner script tag containing the url  http://cdn.walkme.com/users and replace the selected tag with an empty string so can somebody help me with the regex pattern

```
<script><script type="text/javascript">(function() {var walkme = document.createElement('script'); walkme.type = 'text/javascript'; walkme.async = true; walkme.src='http://cdn.walkme.com/users/cb643dab0d6f4c7cbc9d436e7c06f719/walkme_cb643dab0d6f4c7cbc9d436e7c06f719.js'; var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(walkme, s); window._walkmeConfig = {smartLoad:true}; })();</script></script>
```

I have tried this `< script(.+)http://cdn.walkme.com/users/.+?\/script>`

Comment: DO NOT try to parse HTML [with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: Try [this](https://regex101.com/r/3pirwW/1)

Comment: @S.Kablar It works ...thank you...

Comment: Please use HTML Agility pack to parse unvalidated HTML, or XDocument if the string must be valid XML. Regex is the wrong tool for this.

Comment: @DourHighArch ok

Comment: Use [Html Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex)

Answer (score 0):

I agree that it's not really possible to have *comprehensive and generic* regex to parse any (x)HTML which standard supports. That's is true just by nature of these things.

**But** you're perfectly fine to do *lots* of smaller cool tasks using Regex. Just like in your case, in order to strip particular script out of the page markup, you could just use the following regex to find an entry and then replace it with an empty string:

```
\<script\>\<script type="text/javascript"\>\(function\(\) \{var walkme =.*\</script\>
```

It does very a simple thing - takes everything in between

```
<script><script type="text/javascript">(function() {var walkme =
```

(you can include more text to be more specific) and

```
</script>
```

Just ensure special symbols (like /, ( or )) are escaped properly.

**Edited**
In order to select inner  need to use what is called [positive lookahead](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) to find first closing tag right after opening one:

```
<script type="text/javascript">\(function\(\) {var walkme =.*(?=</script>)
```

Comment: The OP specified removing only the inner `script` tag.

Comment: Right, good point. Then the correct expression will be: 
<script type="text/javascript">\(function\(\) {var walkme =.*(?=</script>)